# No se guarda los datos en sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite3

Tengo una base de datos en una ruta como **db.sqlite**.
Pero cuando abro la consola y hago cualquier query, los datos no se guardan

Creo una tabla `CREATE TABLE tabla (id INTEGER)`, en la consola puedo ver que existe la **tabla** y su contenido. Pero cuando hago alguna peticion por otro sitio, me indica que no existe dicha tabla. Y el archivo **db.sqlite** esta vacio, hay 0kb de contenido.

Comment: Tiene permisos de escritura `db.sqlite`?

Comment: Si, tengo permisos de escritura

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has hecho commit de tus cambios.

Al empezar todo:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
```

Despues de todos tus inserts y demas:

```
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Vale gracias, ahora si que funciona